# Font Color change on random Keno card

Tags: excel, vba

I made a program that randomizes the 20 numbers picked on the keno card. However I am having some issues changing the font color on numbers that are picked.

```
 Sub GetRandomCell()
      Range("A1:J10").Select
      Dim i       As Integer
      Dim RNG     As Range
    Set RNG = Range("A1:J10")
      Dim randomCell As Long
      i = 1

    RNG.Interior.Color = vbWhite
    Do While i < 21
    Randomize
    randomCell = Int(Rnd * RNG.Cells.Count) + 1
    If RNG.Cells(randomCell).Interior.Color <> vbGrey Then
        RNG.Cells(randomCell).Interior.Color = vbGrey

        i = i + 1
    End If
Loop
End Sub
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `vbGray` isn't a built in color. You could create a variable, and use that.

Comment: That actually should be vbBlack. It was vbYellow but we don't use a color printer so I was changing it to a darker color. However since the text is black.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could instead check the RGB Value, which allows you to be more specific:

```
If RNG.Cells(randomCell).Interior.Color <> RGB(211, 211, 211) Then
    RNG.Cells(randomCell).Interior.Color = RGB(211, 211, 211)    
    i = i + 1
End If
```

Comment: Good idea. I will use that to set the specific color of the cell, but how then do i change the color of the font?

Comment: @Gehn47 - should just be like, `Cells(#, #).Font.Color = RGB(107, 100, 0)`